# Have style applied onload and then go away with click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to add a class when I click on an element with the class `.tab`

```
     $(function() {
       $(".tab").click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('blueback');
          $(".tab").not($(this)).removeClass('blueback');
       });
     });
```

But I also want the first element `#webtab` to have that class onload, but lose the class when I click on another element.

Comment: the class that i'm adding and removing is `.blueback`

Comment: You have 2 elements with class `tab` and you want to add `blueback` to the element you click. Is it correct understanding?

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems correct. First, you add `blueback` class to the element being clicked and then you select all `tab` elements - remove the current item and them remove `blueblack` from this.

Comment: I got it to work. I had a syntax error in the classes. Thanks

Comment: Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $(".tab").click(function() {
      $(".tab").removeClass('blueback');
      $(this).addClass('blueback');       
   });
});
```

want to help you.